# Where is the castle dynamicproxy repo?

Tags: .net, castle

I can't seem to find the repo for castle dynamic proxy?

I found the code on http://sourceforge.net/projects/castleproject/

I need to fix it so it works in medium trust.

It seems the caste.core assembly needs the allowpartically... attribute in the assembly.cs file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://www.castleproject.org/subversion.html

Comment: this is not valid anymore, see http://github.com/castleproject/ ; each project cluster has been separated
; it now uses msbuild

Answer (score 2):

After this question was accepted the repo has been migrated to github and the DynamicProxy project is now a part of [castle core's project](https://github.com/castleproject/Core)

https://github.com/castleproject/Core/tree/master/src/Castle.Core/DynamicProxy

Answer (score 0):

The repository is [here](https://svn.castleproject.org/svn/castle/DynamicProxy/trunk/), **but**, any relatively new version (trunk) should be working in MT with no issues. If you're having problems running in medium trust, please report them to [the list](http://groups.google.com/group/castle-project-users/), so that it can get a proper, official fix.

Comment: both core and dynamic proxy need to be working in medium trust.

Comment: thanks, if you can: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1829776/help-building-castle-dynamic-proxy

Comment: @both core and dynamic proxy need to be working in medium trust.
 - yeah, don't they? What's the issue?